# Can you create a hotspot in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, image

I have built a site where I have an image. I would like the image to have three hotspots. I noticed that it was quite easy to create in SP2010 but I can't seem to find a answer to how to do it in sp2013. This was done in SharePoint Designer if I am correct.

Comment: With the depreciation of SPD, it might be fun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you still do it using the SP2010, but not sure about the any tool/code from 2013.

You may create a hotspot image from any picture, and you can make it clickable in other HTML editors than SharePoint Designer 2010.Then you can copy the image code and paste it where you want the image to be placed on the SharePoint page.

**Step by step**

- Choose or create an image.
- Create an HTML page in SharePoint Designer 2010.
- Insert the image in the page.
- Select the image to show the Picture Tools.
- Click the Hotspot button and select the form of area you want to
  link.
- "Draw" the area you want to link with the mouse cursor, by holding
  down the left key.
- When you lift the left key, a hyperlink dialog will be displayed.
- Click on the page you want to link to in the list, or write in the
  path.
- Continue in the same way with the other areas you want to link.
- Open the HTML page in Code mode and copy the image code.
- Open the SharePoint page where you want to add the image in Edit
  mode.
- Paste the image code into the SharePoint page on the place where you
  want it.
- Save the page.

[link](http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SPLinksMap.htm)

Comment: This is not the answer he was seeking. The question is whether it can be done in SPD 2013. I believe the answer is that this ability has been removed from SPD 2013.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Image Maps - Released (SharePoint Add-in)

Create interactive images with eye-catching content from within SharePoint. Images contained within a Picture Library will have the option to create an Image Map directly from the image's Context Menu. You can even set the content text to be taken from a SharePoint List for easy updates. The generated Image Map is fully responsive and optimized to work across all devices.

http://sharepointimagemaps.com

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in SharePoint 2013

But I would try to use one of the free online map generators. For example this one:
https://www.image-map.net/

Just create the map and then copy the resulting HTML to the content editor web part.